# How can I design a wormhole in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, technique

How can I design this wormhole using adobe illustrator ?

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: What have you tried? Where is it failing?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out, how I am supposed to start this that's why I am seeking help

Comment: Hard to believe that you have _zero_ ideas on how to start this unless you're a total beginner in Illustrator. I think what you're actually asking is "what's an _easy way_ for drawing this?". I believe that's why you're gathering downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draw a simple curved line like this, and do a 3D revolve on it, using the "Wireframe" option for the surface. Add a bit of an offset to thicken the central pillar.

[image]

When you have finished and you are happy with the general look of it, Expand it, and ungroup until there are no groups left, and delete some of the extra lines.

Rotate it to the orientation you want

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much you made it so easy.

Comment: @David You're welcome. Note that it's not exactly the same as your example, but maybe close enough, eh?

Comment: Yeah that will do the trick, I will do the rest and customize it as required